# Wine touched by non-Jews

Tags: halacha, food, gentiles, grapes-wine

Are you allowed to drink wine that non-Jews touched? Why?

Comment: See [this answer](http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/17/what-makes-a-wine-kosher/708#708) to a related question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even if it is not cooked, a non-Jew merely **touching** the bottle is not enough to prohibit it.

I am not writing a source because it is an inferred answer: If one would look up the Halachos of Yayin Nesech/Stam Yanum in Yorah Deah he will see that what is forbidden is poured wine (and the wine that was in the neck of the bottle as it was being poured and went back into the bottle when it was set down). The concern would be that the Aku"m had in mind to pour it for idolatry. But touching is not even an issue.

Comment: He asked if he touched the wine not the bottle.

Comment: If he touches the actual wine it is a problem.

Comment: You mean he dipped his hands in the wine? I do not believe that's what was meant by the question! There is a common misconception that by merely touching or picking up the bottle a gentile renders wine unfit and my assumption is that his question is based on that misconception.

Comment: Yahu, please give a little more explanation about the term "cooked" as it is a subject of debate as to what this means (eg. flash-pasteurization, actually cooked like used in sauteing food).

Answer (score 2):

According to [Kabbalah](http://www.chabad.org.il/Questions/Item.asp?ArticleID=6750&CategoryID=68), one should avoid drinking wine that was even looked upon by a non-Jew. (The Lubavitcher Rebbe would have the wine covered by farbrengens to avoid this issue).

There is also a [letter](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15912&st=&pgnum=233&hilite=) from the Lubavitcher Rebbe where he says that wine **owned** by a non-shomer-shabbos Jew is forbidden, even if there is a seal within a seal.

Comment: linked: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10493/why-is-this-wine-yayin-nesech

Comment: Is this uniformly accepted by Kabbalists? What sources is this practice based on (eg. Zohar, Ari etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

If it is Mevushal cooked than yes.

Comment: YS, you are correct but the implication you leave readers with is that touching would render the wine unfit and that is simply not true!

Comment: Can you add a source and address Yahu's comment?