# Can a Minor Convert Effect Yayin Nesach?

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism, minor-katan-child, grapes-wine, yayin-nesech

Per the answer to [Are children adopted by Jews Jewish?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13291/are-children-adopted-by-jews-jewish) a child that is adopted by Jewish parents when they reach adulthood (13/12) are given the choice of remaining Jewish.

If I know of a child that is adopted and has not yet reached adulthood - perhaps this child will still choose to live as a gentile when they reach adulthood (13/12) - would this retroactively make wine seen by such a child into Yayin Nesech? (sources)

Comment: Can a child even offer avoda zara?

Comment: @DoubleAA, [that's now asked separately](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16260).

Comment: @msh210 Not exactly. That could always be due to a lo plug.

Comment: @DoubleAA, the question I linked to asks whether a child can make wine _yayin nesech_. That's the only extent to which your question (whether a child can worship) is relevant here, no?

Comment: @msh210 Yes, but that doesn't mean it itself was asked. I said "Not exactly".

Comment: Seen?..........

Comment: In addition to my vague question above, I think you need some support within the body of the question to both explain and justify some of the assumptions made in it.

Comment: If an adult gentle looks at a bottle of wine it does not become Yayin Nesech. This whole question still needs to be rewritten. I get what is being asked, but it is written in a way that demonstrates a misunderstanding of at least two of its major assumptions - that just looking at the wine has a bad effect, and that (the bad action) causes the wine to be Yayin Nesech.

Comment: @SethJ Such a chumra exists of not having non-Jews even look at wine. (I use chumra in the most simplistic sense, ie this is not an opinion that's shared by rov rishonim or anything. In fact, I'm not aware of any rishon requiring it.)

Comment: @SethJ Hmmm here is an unsourced source http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13307/759

Comment: @doubleaa it's still not Y"N.

Comment: @SethJ I'm completely with you, but something tells me GershonGold wasn't being very meduyak in his word choice.

Comment: I think that a lot of people make that mistake (I did for a while), even if they have an above average level of Jewish education. I think, ultimately, it is something worth pointing out, if only to inform future readers.

Answer (score 5):

The Pischei Teshuva ([YD 268:8](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9147&st=&pgnum=194&hilite=)) quoting the Tiferes L'Moshe writes that in the event that the child reverts to the status of a gentile, all the wine s/he has touched will indeed retain the status of wine touched by a gentile child. He qualifies this by saying that we aren't concerned that it might happen until it does, and we allow the kid to touch our wines.