# Is wine touched/shaken by a non-idolatrous Gentile child forbidden to drink?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, minor-katan-child, grapes-wine

[Shulchan Aruch (YD 124:1)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9146&st=&pgnum=61) states:

> A Nochri child who does not mention idolatry or Meshamshim, if he
>   touched wine he forbids only drinking it, but not benefit from it.

(See this [related question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16260/would-a-gentile-child-that-sees-touches-wine-make-it-into-yayin-nesech).)

Would this prohibition be only in the case of a gentile child who is an idolator or also in the case of a non-idolatrous one — i.e. would the wine be permitted to drink if a non-idolatrous gentile child touched it?

Comment: First of all, [as has been established elsewhere on the site](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1002/5), merely touching the bottle would not make it Yayin Nesech. Second, Yayin Nesech is the wrong term - it's only Yayin Nesech if it _has been_ used for a libation. Otherwise it's Stam Yeiynam.

Comment: @SethJ who mentioned touching the bottle?

Comment: You did. "Would a Gentile baby/child that touch/shake an open container of wine..."

Comment: @DoubleAA I Edited the question only to include my third question which wasn't included in the other duplicate question.

Comment: much better question, IMHO.

Comment: Why do you ask only by a child? You could ask the same question on an adult, I believe.

Answer (score 3):

From [Avoda Zara 57a](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.57a.4?with=all&lang=bi) we see that even a baby who is one day old renders the wine prohibited for drinking:

> אמרו ליה רב כהנא ורב אסי לרב והא מר הוא דאמר תינוק בן יומו הוא עושה יין נסך אמר להו אימור דאמרי אנא בשתייה בהנאה מי אמרי
>
> Rav Kahana and Rav Asi said to Rav: But wasn’t it you, Master, who said: If a gentile baby who is one day old touches wine, he renders it wine used for a libation, even though he lacks any intent? Rav said to them: Say that I said that the baby renders the wine prohibited for drinking. Did I say that it is prohibited to derive benefit from it? It is therefore permitted to sell the wine.

The same is repeated by the [Be'er Hetev Y"D 124:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Ba%27er_Hetev_on_Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De%27ah.124.1?with=all&lang=):

> בשתיה. ואיתא בש''ס דאפילו תינוק בן יומו עושה יי''נ בשתיה וכן הוא בפוסקים

The Tur ([YD 124:1)](https://www.sefaria.org/Tur,_Yoreh_Deah.124.1?with=all&lang=bi) says that Only an adult, who understand what he's doing when it comes to idol worship, can make the wine asur in having pleasure from, but a child who didn't reach this definition, only makes it asur for drinking but not for pleasure.

> **Would this prohibition be only in the case of a gentile child who is an idolator or also in the case of a non-idolatrous one**

Well, from the above sources we see, that even a child who is not an idolator, makes the wine *asur* to drink.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Ben Ish Chai, a prominent 19th century rabbi of Bagdhad, a Moslem child does not make the wine forbidden. This is found in the four volume English edition of "Halachos of the Ben Ish Chai"